# How to Implement NetworkAvailabilityChanged in WPF with MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, network-programming, network-interface

I have a WPF application, which requires use of NetworkAvailablityChanged to determine when a user has changed from disconnected from the network. However, I am developing my application using the MVVM pattern. So I'm not quite sure how to use this to where it will begin monitoring as soon as the application has started. Any advice on the best way to implement this or perhaps a better way to monitor all of the computer's network interfaces?

Update: From my understanding of MVVM, the Model interacts with the data. In this case, the data would be what is returned when the connection to the active network interface changes. However, if I put this in the model I do not know of a way to make it start monitoring when the application starts. Simply, I need to create a method that monitors the network interfaces and returns whether the current active interface is an Ethernet interface, 802.11 Wireless interface, or if there is no connection at all. Then based on that I'll call the proper property in my model.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague right now. Can you explain exactly what you have a problem with?

Comment: See update to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes purity of architecture interferes with simplicity of design.  This sounds like one of those cases.

Continue to use MVVM to structure your application's work and data flow.  However temporal indicators (like network availability) and error conditions (like out of disk space) don't cleanly fit into these models and are best deal with independently.

Comment: Independently how? What would you do if you needed to do something like this?

Comment: Directly subscribe to the NetworkAvailabilityChanged event from your view and modify the UI (say a green status button icon in the status bar) when it changes.  I wouldn't create a Model or ViewModel for the data.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "subscribe to the NetworkAvailabilityChanged event"?

Comment: See the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx).  You'll need to get back onto the right WPF thread using [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx).

Comment: But why does it need to be done on a different thread? I mean since the application calls the ViewModel automatically, could I not just call a function in the constructor which does the same as what is shown in that example? If that would work then it would not need to be on a different thread would it?

Comment: When the event is fired, it's not fired on the Dispatcher/UI thread so your callback delegate isn't running on the Dispatcher thread.  This is why you need to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke before you touch the UI (e.g. turn the status icon from green to red).

Comment: After talking with my boss, it turns out that she just wants me to get all of the MAC addresses. Therefore, I no longer need to do this. I updated my code to get all of the Ethernet and Wireless MAC addresses excluding the MAC addresses from the Tunnel adapters. I also put something in there to keep it from getting the MAC address of an adapter that was created by VMware or VirtualBox.